# AHK Reverse sort on file list

Tags: autohotkey

I cannot get a reverse sort on my list. I'm not understanding how to correctly sort my files by name, last modified, or any attribute.

```
Gui, Add, Text, title?, Pick a file to launch from the list below.`nTo cancel, press ESCAPE or close this window.
Gui, Add, ListBox, vMyListBox gMyListBox w500 r5
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK

Loop files, C:\Users\me\Downloads\*.png  
  {
    FileList = %A_LoopFileName% 
    Sort, FileList, R  ; Sort, reverse order.
    GuiControl,, MyListBox, %FileList%
  }
Gui, Show, w550 h140, hello
return


MyListBox:
if (A_GuiEvent != "DoubleClick")
    return
ButtonOK:
GuiControlGet, MyListBox 

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm doing a loop in a loop basically. Or something is wrong that I can't fully describe. But it'll work better to first draw out the list, then sort it, then apply to the gui like so...

```
Gui, Add, Text, title?, Pick a file to launch from the list below.`nTo cancel, press ESCAPE or close this window.
Gui, Add, ListBox, vMyListBox gMyListBox w500 r5
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK

FileList := 
Loop files, C:\Users\me\Downloads\*.png
  {
    FileList .= A_LoopFileName . "|"
  }
Sort, FileList, R D|  ; Sort, reverse order. Use '|' as the Delimiter.


GuiControl,, MyListBox, %FileList%
Gui, Show, w550 h140, hello
return

MyListBox:
if (A_GuiEvent != "DoubleClick")
    return
ButtonOK:
GuiControlGet, MyListBox 

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

If a sort on last modified or created is needed. You can add this to the list while building it out in the loop and then remove it later AFTER the sort has occurred using a regexreplace on 14 digit number.

```
Gui, Add, Text, title?, Pick a file to launch from the list below.`nTo cancel, press ESCAPE or close this window.
Gui, Add, ListBox, vMyListBox gMyListBox w500 r5
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK

FileList := 
Loop files, C:\Users\me\Downloads\*.png
  {
    FileList .= A_LoopFileTimeModified "," A_LoopFileName "|"
  }
Sort, FileList, R D|  ; Sort, reverse order. Use '|' as the Delimiter.
NewFileList .= RegExReplace(FileList,"[0-9]{14},","")

GuiControl,, MyListBox, %NewFileList%
Gui, Show, w550 h140, hello
return

MyListBox:
if (A_GuiEvent != "DoubleClick")
    return
ButtonOK:
GuiControlGet, MyListBox 

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

Comment: you could also use the `A_LoopFileTimeCreated` variable in the second script to show last created by sorting.